# jQuery get anchor value

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to get the value of a clicked anchor but I am not sure which anchor is being clicked or how to latch onto it with jquery.  I have a document.ready function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var ActiveBlogStats = $('#BlogSelectList');
$('#BlogSelectList').click(function () {
    alert(ActiveBlogStats.text)
}); })
```

Here is the id that it is working on

```
<ul class="submenu" id="BlogSelectList">
  <xsl:for-each select="oohru/user/oohblog">
    <li>
      <a>
        <xsl:attribute name="href">#<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(blogid)"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="oohblogurl"/>
      </a>
    </li>
  </xsl:for-each>
<li><a href="AddNewBlog.aspx">+ Create a new oohblog</a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I get the href of the actual anchor being clicked?  I don't see how to make a document.ready even for items that don't exist until after the document is ready.
I suppose I could get the # value from the URL since when they click one it will update the URL but I would rather get it directly from the click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your content is dynamically generated, you may want to look into .live() (or delegate()) ( http://api.jquery.com/live/ | http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Your code would then look something like:

```
    $("#BlogSelectList li a").live('click', function () {
        //do something
    });
```

Comment: I ended up using 
`$("#BlogSelectList li a").live('click', function () {
                    alert($(this).attr("href"))
                });`

which is very nearly what you suggested it just needed an li before the anchor since there was an element [li] between the anchor and the BlogSelectList

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#BlogSelectList a").click(function(){

var href = $(this).attr("href");



});
```

Comment: Problem with this is it triggers for every anchor on the page not just the ones within BlogSelectList

Answer (score 0):

You could get the href with something like this:

```
$("#BlogSelectList").delegate("a", "click", function() {

    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    alert(href);

});
```

And if you needed to stop it from redirecting, you could do:

```
$("#BlogSelectList").delegate("a", "click", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    alert(href);

});
```

Comment: You are going to want to use [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) so that it will trigger on any anchor that's added, even after the document is ready.

Comment: only if there's a common parent that will stay constant in the page.  Since he's talking about chunks of the document that won't exist on document ready, we can't assume that there will be any static parent.  In theory, 'body' can be used, but that's too vague for my tastes.

Comment: This one isn't working, is it because the anchor is not a direct child of BlogSelectList? Technically Anchor is a child of li which is a direct child of BlogSelectList.  I tried using "li.a" or "li a" neither seemed to do anything no event is triggered